# when trying to restore .bak file Restore-SPSite : <nativehr> 0x00070003 </nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

When trying to restore .bak file facing `"Restore-SPSite : <nativehr> 0x00070003 </nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>"`

And in the event viewer:

> A database error occurred. Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider Code:
>   -2 occurred 0 time(s) Description:  Error ordinal: 1 Message: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while
>   attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This
>   could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was
>   unable to respond back in time.

How to fix this?

Comment: Can you also add the ULS log errors ?

Answer (score 0):

When you restore a site from (assumingly) another farm you need to make sure that the destination farm is at the same patch level as the source farm. The destination farm can also have a higher (newer) patch level, but I've experienced failing to restore a site in this setup.

The easiest way to check is to run the following script on both farms, and verify the output.

```
(Get-SPFarm).BuildVersion
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Destination environment is high version. So how should restore? thanks

Comment: @samdaniel Patch the source farm to the same patch level, and then backup->restore

Comment: Is there any other way because I'm not allowed to do anything in source farm but have full control on destination environment

Comment: @samdaniel You could uninstall patches from destination farm instead, making both farms equal

Comment: How to do revert patches and where to uninstall? in SQL?

Comment: @samdaniel On SharePoint servers, and then make a new ConfigDB

Answer (score 0):

Check in Event Viewer.
Possibilities:

1. SharePoint versions are different.
2. Insufficient SQL Database permission for particular user.
3. Managed path issue.

OR

Try to restore with host header web application.

```
Restore-SPSite http://www.example.com -Path \\file_server\share\site_name.bak -HostHeaderWebApplication http://server_name
```